# Meizu Pro 5 - 13.5 GB of internal storage "used by Ubuntu"

Tags: ubuntu-touch, disk-usage, storage

I own the Meizu Pro 5 for a month already and am using it as a daily driver. However I have recently noticed in memory information section that 13.5 GB of my internal memory is "used by Ubuntu". I have been checking this every few days recently, and each time I checked it had increased. Is it a known bug? How can I clean some of it if it gets even more?

[image: Memoty usage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gps daemon has logging enabled and is consuming a large amount of disk in /userdata/android-data/gps/log

Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1595704 which has a script to clean up the files. This is fixed in the rc-proposed channel and will be in OTA 12.

Comment: In the bug comments there is a workaround, which worked. Thank you!